# How many six digit integers contain zero exactly twice.

Tags: combinatorics

I can't seem to figure this out. We're provided with the answer (65610) but no matter what I do , I can't seem to find the mathematically.

My idea was to let A = the number of six digit integers = $9*10^5$

Then let B = some number such that $A - B$ = 65610

I also thought about $9^3 * 10^3$ but that doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: You need to choose places for $0$s (where the first digit is not $0$), so you have ${5\choose 2}$ options and then you have $4$ places to put any digit between $1$ and $9$, hence $9^4$ options, so in total ${5\choose 2}\cdot{9^4}=65610$.

Comment: The number of six digit integers would be 10^6...

Comment: Thegreatduck.  The op is assuming kin this case correctly) a six digit number can't start with 0.

Comment: Calculate the number of ways to have a 6 digit number where the last digit is 0.  Then the 2nd digit is zero and so on.  You should be able to convince yourself there are 5 places the first 0 can go, and 4 the 2nd can and as order doesn't matter 10 ways to place 2 zeros.  The remaining 4 places can have 9 digits so answer is 10x9^4.

Comment: You can subtract unwanted numbers but then you have to calculate the number of 6 digits with exactly 3 zeros.  And that's exactly the same level of difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

It’s much easier to calculate the desired number directly than to calculate the number of *un*wanted numbers and subtract that from the total.

There are $\binom52$ ways to pick two of the digit positions for the zeroes, since the first digit can’t be $0$. There are $9$ possible digits for each of the other $4$ positions, so the total number of possibilities is

$$\binom52\cdot9^4=10\cdot6561=65,610\;.$$